# Nginx - Redirect chain

Tags: redirect, nginx

According to an online redirect checker, the following chain happens on some of my pages:

```
https://website.com/ar/page/
301 ->
http://website.com/es/page/
301 ->
https://website.com/es/page/
301 ->
https://website.com/es/page
```

For some reason, the redirect from `/ar/` to `/es/` changes the `https` to `http`.

Here is my redirect code:

```
rewrite ^/ar/(.+)$ /es/$1 permanent;
```

Is there a way to ensure the redirect keeps the https?

Comment: Use: `https://$host/es/$1`

Comment: Perfect, thank you.